# Where to find Win XP chipset drivers for ASUS A6R?

Tags: drivers, chipset

I tried to search the manufacturer's page at http://support.asus.com.tw/download, but there is no Win XP chipset Drivers. I found something under Utility Category (SMBus Driver) and tried to install most of the drivers provided, but the Device Manager still reports error at these devices:

- Base System Device
- Network Controller
- Video Controller (VGA Compatible)

The graphic Card is ATI Radeon Xpress 200M, no success with search and install this driver. I have no install CD. I do not know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link for the drivers for your system:

http://drp.su/drivers/notebooks/?v=ASUS&m=A6R&id=665&l=en

If you still need help, post back.

Comment: That was rather freaky: video controller now works fine, but World of Warcraft Trial was installed without warning.